# Writing a file into Amazon S3 AWS Storage using Scala

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

this is part of my code:

```
   val file=new File("s3a://tracce/output/Tempi.txt") 
   val writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true))
   writer.write("Execution Time trace "+count.toString+"x"+i.toString+": "+differenza.toString)
   writer.newLine()
   writer.flush()
   writer.close()
```

I need to write a new file into my bucket using Scala. 
I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:     s3:/tracce/output/Tempi.txt (No such file or directory)
```

When I try to save it locally, it works:

```
val file=new File("./Tempi.txt")
```

How could I solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an AWS Java SDK that makes doing this pretty easy

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_s3.html

Comment: it works with RDD, I need to write a simple string

Comment: Have you tried looking at the example that AWS gives for uploading a file? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Answer (score 8):

You can now write it directly using the AWS Java SDK. Here is the example;

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.{AmazonS3, AmazonS3ClientBuilder}

val s3Client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()

val bucketName = "bucket-name"
val objectKey = "object-key"
val objectContent = "This is the file content."

s3Client.putObject(bucketName, objectKey, objectContent)
```

Answer (score 4):

S3A being a Hadoop Filesystem client, you can't use the java File API to work with it.

1. Create a hadoop `Configuration` object with all your s3 credentials in them. If you are using Spark, you get that for free from `SparkContext`.
2. Use the Hadoop FS API to get the FS instance, `create()` to create a file in it.

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "YOUR ACCESS KEY")
    conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "YOUR SECRET KEY")

    val dest = new Path("s3a://bucket_name/output-path/file.txt")
    val fs = dest.getFileSystem(conf)
    val out = fs.create(dest, true)
    out.write( /* your string as bytes */ )
    out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 being an object store, you cannot write strings. You can probably write the strings to a local file and periodically upload the file to S3.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
  def uploadDataToS3Bucket(baseDF: DataFrame): Unit = {
    // AWS S3 credentials and bucket information
    val accessKeyId = "YourAccessKey"
    val secretAccessKey = "YourSecretKey"
    val s3BucketName = "BucketName"
    val s3OutputPath = "path\filename.csv"
    val csvData = "id\tname\n1\tJohn\n2\tJane\n3\tAlice"
    
    // Set up AWS credentials
    System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", accessKeyId)
    System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", secretAccessKey)

    // Explicitly specify the AWS region
    val region = Regions.US_EAST_1

    // Create an AmazonS3 client
    val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
      .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
      .withRegion(region.getName)
      .build()

    // Convert the CSV data to an InputStream
    val inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(csvData.getBytes)

    // Set the metadata for the object
    val metadata = new ObjectMetadata()
    metadata.setContentLength(csvData.getBytes.length)
    metadata.setContentType("text/csv")

    // Upload the data to S3
    val request = new PutObjectRequest(s3BucketName, s3OutputPath, inputStream, metadata)
    s3Client.putObject(request)

    println("Uploaded data to S3.")
  }
```